# Gram-Schmidt Process

Tags: linear-algebra

I've discovered the Orthogonalize command:

```
Clear[x1, x2]
x1 = {1, 1, 0};
x2 = {-2, 0, 1};
Orthogonalize[{x1, x2}, Method -> "GramSchmidt"]
```

Which returns an orthonormal basis.

$$
\left\{
\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2},0\right\}
\left\{-\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right\}
\right\}
$$

However, student textbooks that introduce the Gram-Schmidt Process return an orthogonal basis, not unit vectors.

I am wondering if there is a simple Mathematica command I am missing that will do the latter?

Granted, I can do this:

```
Clear[v1, v2]
v1 = x1;
v2 = x2 - ((x2.x1)/(x1.x1)) x1;
{v1, v2}
```

Which returns:

$$\left\{
\left\{1,1,0\right\},
\left\{-1,1,1\right\}
\right\}$$

But what I am wondering is have I missed a single Mathematica command that will do this?

Comment: I don't think I understand why one would *not* want orthonormalized vectors... in any event, you might be interested in `Projection[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Orthogonal component to a subspace, least squares solution? (I think it's a question of elementary theory vs computation.)  In any case, the OP wishes to illustrate the textbook process.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider giving an appropriate second argument (inner product function) to `Orthogonalize`. For example,

```
In[66]:= vs2 = Orthogonalize[{x1, x2}, Dot[##]*Norm[#] &, Method -> "GramSchmidt"]

Out[66]= {{1/2^(3/4), 1/2^(3/4), 0}, {-(1/3^(3/4)), 1/3^(3/4), 1/3^(3/4)}}

In[67]:= Outer[Dot, vs2, vs2, 1]

Out[67]= {{1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {0, 1/Sqrt[3]}}
```

If you want to take that route (instead of using `Projection` as J.M. suggests) it might be useful to examine the output of

```
Clear[f];
Orthogonalize[{x1, x2}, f, Method -> "GramSchmidt"]
```

Comment: So the dot product you would "need" is Dot[##]/Norm[#1]/Norm[2], but that's not a dot product, hence [unexpected results](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-orthogonalize-bug.nb)